# Is it possible to edit the source representation of objects in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, xml

I often find myself copying and pasting worksheets in order to show the same analysis for different sets of data. This includes graphs. It's irritating having to 'select data' for every data series, error bars, etc. for every data set.

Once I have created a graph for one worksheet, my choices are:

- Copy the graph to another worksheet. Use 'select data' for every part
- Copy the entire worksheet, then replace the data

I would much prefer to be able to see the XML (or whatever) representation behind the graph and be able to do a find-and-replace on the worksheet names/column names. The Excel interface gets in the way a lot and doesn't make it easy to change the graph repeatedly (particularly for error bars).

**Is there some textual representation of objects like graphs I can edit?** (I'd rather not mess around with extracting the xlsx file and editing the XML files in a text editor).

Comment: You should be able to modify your charts using VBA. Also, if applicable, modify the chart source tables instead of the charts.

Answer (score 0):

Insert data to Excel 2007 from ...

[image: link dato to excel]

Open CSV file

[image: Open CSV file]

open wizard part I

[image: open wizard part I]

open wizard part II

[image: open wizard part II]

open wizard part III

[image: open wizard part III]

insert cell choice

[image: insert cell choice]

refreash data options from  CSV file

[image: refreash data options from CSV file]

view CSV file in Far Manager

[image: view CSV file in Far Manager]

Set type of chart

[image: set type of chart]

Edit CSV file

[image: Edit CSV file]

Refreash Excel data

[image: Refreash Excel data]

Edit CSV file

[image: Edit CSV file]

Refreash Excel data

[image: Refreash Excel data]

Security data setting

[image: Security data setting]

It all. If need insert rotate table and graph picture).

Comment: At this point it's probably simpler to feed your data from a database (such as sql server) rather than edit CSV files, for the same result.

Comment: Yes, easier to use ms sql server. You can add screens to connect and work with a database and write stored procedures. I do not mind.

Answer (score 0):

How about editing the series formulas? I have a tutorial at [Change Series Formula – Improved Routines](https://peltiertech.com/change-series-formula-improved-routines/), but the gist is as follows:

The series formula looks like this:
`=SERIES(Sheet1!$B$1,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$11,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$11,1)`

The arguments mean:
`=SERIES([Series Name],[X Values],[Y Values],[Plot Order])`

You access these formulas in VBA using something like 
`ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula`

You can use the following to change a part of the formula from `OldString' to 'NewString':

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula = WorksheetFunction.Substitute( _
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula, OldString, NewString)
```

You can wrap this into a nice VBA procedure that asks the user for that old string to replace with what new string, then makes the changes to all series in the active chart:

```
Sub ChangeSeriesFormula()
    ''' Just do active chart
    If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
        '' There is no active chart
        MsgBox "Please select a chart and try again.", vbExclamation, _
            "No Chart Selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim OldString As String, NewString As String, strTemp As String
    Dim mySrs As Series

    OldString = InputBox("Enter the string to be replaced:", "Enter old string")

    If Len(OldString) > 1 Then
        NewString = InputBox("Enter the string to replace " & """" _
            & OldString & """:", "Enter new string")
        '' Loop through all series
        For Each mySrs In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
            strTemp = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(mySrs.Formula, _
                OldString, NewString)
            mySrs.Formula = strTemp
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing to be replaced.", vbInformation, "Nothing Entered"
    End If
End Sub
```

The tutorial I cited above has more examples of how to edit series formulas.