# Windows Xp, Excel 2003 automatic start on bootup and yes to update

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-excel-2003

I need to start an excel file on startup. However when opening the software always ask if the user wants to update the files. How can I get Excel to automatically do this every time?

Comment: See: Security data setting, [Is it possible to edit the source representation of objects in Excel?][1]


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/545908/is-it-possible-to-edit-the-source-representation-of-objects-in-excel/546022#546022

Comment: Are `Tools > Options > Calculations > Calculation > Automatic` and `Tools > Options > Calculations > Workbook options > Update remote references` selected?

Comment: what do you mean by "update the files"?